# How do I keep a div center when browser window goes smaller than div size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Essentially when the browser window goes larger thh div stays centered and creates white space on the outside. I want the same thing to happen when the browser window goes smaller. I want to see less of the div but keep it centered. At the moment I see less of the div but the left side locks so I end up only seeing a slither of the left part of the image (instead of the center). Sorry if this is a convoluted way of asking I am new to programming. Any help would be massively appreciated! Thanks in advance! :)

p.s I am also struggling to have the video playing if anyone can help with that too

Here is my code currently

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#page-container {
  width: 1920px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-container">
  <video id="backgroundvid" width="auto" autoplay>
    <source  src="assets/video/portalAnimLowRes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ben and welcome to SO. Do you mean having responsive scaling where the video is in the vertical and horizontal center?

Comment: Thank you :) Yes but just the horizontal center. Selim Achour's suggestion below worked perfectly! :D Any thoughts on why my video does not work?

Comment: Videos tend to be blocked from playing when they don't have a `muted` attribute. It prevents sites from annoyingly starting video's without your permission. Otherwise it could be that the path to your file is incorrect. And although Selim's answer works, it's an oldschool technique. If you're starting out and are willing to learn then checkout [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for building your layouts.

Comment: Yes thank you this work perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
#page-container {
    width:1920px;
    margin-left: -960px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the pageContainer on `absolute` position as follows.

```
#page-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 1920px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want the horizontal scroll bar?

If you don't, I prefer not to define the width(especially in pixel), as the width of every device varies.

Instead, you can define width as `width:100%` or `width:100vw`, this helps to fit the div according to the screen size.

You can try this code:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
#page-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about use flexbox?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#page-container {
  width: 1920px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-container">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
</div>
```